# Yet again: "expected type parameter, found struct"

Tags: generics, rust

There are already a couple of questions regarding this particular error message. I read them all, but I cannot figure out what the exact problem is that I am facing here, nor how I can fix it.

I have a `struct` that has a requirement on the argument that is passed in, and I want to provide a few convenience functions for constructing a new instance. Here it comes:

```
use std::io::{Cursor, Read, Seek};

pub struct S<R: Read + Seek> {
    p: R,
}

impl<R: Read + Seek> S<R> {
    pub fn new(p: R) -> Self {
        S { p }
    }

    pub fn from_string(s: String) -> Self {
        S::new(Cursor::new(s))
    }
}
```

The above minimal example gives the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:13:16
   |
13 |         S::new(Cursor::new(s))
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter, found struct `std::io::Cursor`
   |
   = note: expected type `R`
              found type `std::io::Cursor<std::string::String>`
   = help: here are some functions which might fulfill your needs:
           - .into_inner()
```

I tried many variations, but I always end up with the same error. Also note that calling `S::new` with a cursor from somewhere else (e.g. `main`) works as expected. I know that it has to do with the generic, and so on (from the answers to other similar questions) but: *How can I provide such `from_*` methods along the `impl` of my `struct`?*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error message is not that far off in this case, I think.  Your `impl` says:

```
impl<R: Read + Seek> S<R>
```

so your `new` function should create a type which is variable in `R`, but you only supply a fixed type, `Cursor<String>`.  Try this instead:

```
use std::io::{Cursor, Read, Seek};

pub struct S<R: Read + Seek> {
    p: R,
}

impl<R: Read + Seek> S<R> {
    pub fn new(p: R) -> Self {
        S { p }
    }

}

impl S<Cursor<String>> {
    pub fn from_string(s: String) -> Self {
        S::new(Cursor::new(s))
    }
}
```

Comment: Now everything starts to make sense, many thanks. =)